# Is there a difference between "Grecian" and "Greek"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, demonyms

As far as I can tell, "Grecian" and "Greek" both mean "of or pertaining to Greece." Is there any difference at all between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Modern English, *Greek* is the usual adjective meaning *of or pertaining to Greece*.

*Grecian* is an earlier construction, with an adjective-forming *-an* suffix (*American, Norwegian, Virginian*), which is now pretty much relegated to stylistic and fixed phrase duty. It's common in the following expressions, among others:

- *[Grecian Formula](http://www.grecian-formula.com/)*
- *[Grecian urn](http://www.google.com/search?q=grecian+urn&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=I6R_T--AH9Do2gXQ7YCFBw&biw=1087&bih=954&sei=KKR_T_wGg9rZBZHskIgH)*
- *[Grecian style](http://www.google.com/search?q=grecian+style)* or *Grecian dress*
- *[Grecian sandals](http://www.google.com/search?q=grecian+sandals)*

But there is no *Grecian restaurant, Grecian wine,* or *Grecian language*.

Comment: No Grecian yogurt.

Comment: 'What's a Grecian urn?' 'Just a few drachmas a week.'

Comment: Many instances of *Grecian* in the later half of your answer. True. But why? What makes a Grecian urn different from _ Greek urn. (Well, there *can* be a Greek urn).

Comment: Just the fashion, ma'am, just the fashion. Note that one of the phrases is a trademark for a men's cosmetic, two are women's clothing styles, and the other is attached to a rarely-used or -understood word that was briefly fashionable in certain circles (i.e, it's an idiom). _Grecian urn_ was a popular phrase in the 19th century, when _Grecian_ was in fashion. That's all; just the remains of deceased adjectives.

Answer (score 4):

"Grecian" means "in a style used by the inhabitants of Greece," and so anyone could make, say, a Grecian urn. "Greek" means either an inhabitant of Greece, or from Greece, so a Greek urn must come from Greece.

Comment: I disagree.  If you mix lettuce with olives, feta cheese, and chunks of meat, that's a Greek salad.

Answer (score 3):

*Grecian* in my experience seems to used solely to describe the esthetic product of Classical Greek culture.  Thus, *a Grecian urn* but *a Greek soldier*; *Grecian pillars* but *Greek philosophy*.  And of course, *Grecian Formula* but *Greek financial collapse*.

Comment: While that's a pattern, a common title of Plutarch's _Lives_ is _Lives of the Noble Grecians and Romans_; I don't think all these noble Grecians were particularly aesthetic products.

Comment: @JasonFruit -- in 1668, when Dryden published the first complete English translation of *Lives*, "Grecian" might have been the word for a Greek person (or just an Ancient Greek person), but I don't think that's been true for a while.

Comment: No doubt that customary title survived to the late 19th-Century edition I have.

Comment: Reading now the 6th volume of Grote's History of Ancient Greece published in 1846, I can state that at the time 'Grecian' was a commonly adjective, not limited to arts and esthetics.  Here is a sentence I'm reading: "Thucydides has taken advantage of it to give a sort of general sketch of Grecian politics during the Peloponnesian war..."  He seldom uses 'Greek' as an adjective.